# Behaviors reference not found?

Tags: c#, wpf

Well to create a system where I can easily attach my viewmodel to a view, and keep track of the selected items in a list in the view. - Yet without hard binding both. I tried to follow a certain "recipe" I found [here](http://igrali.com/2015/03/06/pass-listview-selecteditems-to-viewmodel-in-universal-apps/).

Now I already have a direct problem starting that:

> The method I'll use in this post uses EventTriggerBehavior to invoke a
>   command in ViewModel when a SelectionChanged event occurs. For that to
>   work, you need to add the Behaviors SDK to both of your projects
>   (Windows and Windows Phone) in your Universal app.

When I open the references of the project I don't see a "windows phone 8.1" (Obviously as I don't create a windows phone app). In the "framework" references, however, I do not see the listed sdks - interactivity/behaviors sdk I can't find in any reference.

Now I already noticed the code completion added an schema for "interactivity" by default already: `xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"` - so maybe the sdks are already installed for windows applications. And I just tried the next thing, include the "core" namespace:

```
<xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core" />
```

Sadly, this failed, the code highlighter gives an error for the `Xaml.Interactions.Core` part, stating those are not existing. (Leading me to believe I have to go back to step 1 above).

So what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `System.Windows.Interactivity` using NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF/. You can then use the InvokeCommandAction type:

```
<ListView Name="MyListOfImportantThings" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListView>
```

Please refer to the following blog post for more information: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/06/30/handling-events-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application/.

Universal apps and WPF don't use the same XAML stack.

Comment: +1 for the "Universal apps and WPF don't use the same XAML stack." - that actually explained a lot of troubles I was having at different parts. I'll try the solution given here.